# Django Static Images Not Loading

Tags: html, django

I have images downloaded in the following path but they refuse to load for me. Any idea what I may have configured incorrectly that is forcing this?

C:\Users\xxx\Python\Price Tracking\Django\mysite\polls\static\polls\images

- stl.jpg
- chicago.jpg
- nyc.jpg

[image]

settings:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'polls.apps.PollsConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django_plotly_dash.apps.DjangoPlotlyDashConfig',
]

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

html:

```
{% load static %}

    <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="{% static 'polls/chicago.jpg' %}" alt="First slide">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="{% static 'polls/nyc.jpg' %}" alt="Second slide">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="{% static 'polls/stl.jpg' %}" alt="Third slide">
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Your html should read `<img class="d-block w-100" src="{% static 'polls/images/chicago.jpg' %}" alt="First slide">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you write that images are in ... polls/static/polls/images/ but in the template tag you have /polls/xyz.jpg

For the rest you need to tell if you are in development with runserver and Debug=True (then files are taken from the app/static folders as you place them) or in deployment on e.g. a Apache server (then you need to serve them from Apache directly ... see serving static files on django docs

Comment: Shouldn't the Settings.py file tell it to look for */static/ and then start there, which would cut off the rest of the path and leave me with path/nyc.jpg (aka what I have)? Also, this is currently on my offline server http://127.0.0.1:7000/.

Comment: Runserver will look in your apps/static/+path from your template tag {% static 'path/file' %}

Comment: 127.0.0.1:7000 is served by runserver or another?

Comment: I also just tried updating polls/nyc.jpg to polls/static/nyc.jpg with no luck

Comment: Weirdly enough, some images work while some do not even within the same folder... Are there any other requirements that I'm not thinking of?

Comment: No. 100% sure the files are in the folder? And no typos in the template tag for the path and filename and extension?